# ASP anchor tag helper asp-action attrubute without asp-controller attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In my `ASP.NET Core RC2` app I created a view using VS2015 `view Wizard` where I selected `Details demplate`. At the end of the view, it created the following HTML tags. If you notice that the anchor tags have asp-action attributes but not the asp-Controller attributes. But the Edit and Index links take me to the right controller that is the controller the wizard used to create Details template. My assumptiopn is that by default the `Edit and Index actions` are called in the same controller the Details template is using. Is my assumption correct? Where the asp-controller attribute needed? If it's not there what is the assumption?

**Details view**:

```
...other tags here...
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.CustomerID">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, links are generated using the same controller as the current action if the `asp-controller` attribute is not provided.